# How to "INJECT" with holding Evaluation, specifically into a WhenEvent

Tags: differential-equations, probability-or-statistics, pattern-matching, hold

I am importing a set of differential and stochastic equations from an external package, and want to use Mathematica to analyse this.

I am struggling building the set of equations that I can use with `NDSolve`, especially because I cannot stop one equation from evaluating prematurely.

A simple explanation; the below set of functions would be the result from fitting a empirical dataset and transforming this fit into something suitable for use with `NDSolve`:

```
{
  a[t] -> Length[Select[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[x[t], 2],10], #1 > .3&]],
  b[t] -> Length[Select[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[a[t], 10],10], #1 > .3 &]]
}
```

**I do however never arrive at this stage**, as the `rhs` will evaluate into `0` or `1` **so I use `Hold` to keep the above `rhs` from evaluating** into something incorrect as the variables in `Length`, `RandomVariate` and `NormalDistribution` are not defined in this context (only within the `NDSolve` context).

I changed the transformation to result into:

```
inject = {
   Hold[a[t]] -> Hold[Length[Select[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[x[t], 2],10], #1 > .3 &]]], 
   Hold[b[t]] -> Hold[Length[Select[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[a[t],10],10], #1 > .3 &]]]
};
```

What I want to achieve is to build something like the following expression (in reality it will be a much higher order):

```
NDSolve[
  {x'[t] == b[t] Sin[a[t] t], x[0] == 0, b[0] == 1, a[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, .01] == 0,
    {
     a[t] -> Length[Select[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[x[t], 2], 10], # > .3 &]], 
     b[t] -> Length[Select[RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[a[t]], 10], # > .3 &]]
    }]}, x, {t, 100}, DiscreteVariables -> {a, b}]
```

I was naive enough to hope something like the below would work, which seems not to be the case as the events are not dynamically updating the states ....

```
NDSolve[
  {x'[t] == b[t] Sin[a[t] t], x[0] == 0, b[0] == 1, a[0] == 0,
   WhenEvent[Mod[t, .01] == 0,
    {
    ReleaseHold[inject]
    }]}, x, {t, 100}, DiscreteVariables -> {a, b}]
```

Is there a way to "inject" this into `NDSolve`? What should I change when using `ReleaseHold`does not work, or is changing the structure of the expression to be injected the way to go?

I tried using `Strings` but that creates a lot of complexities in the variuous transformations I have to do, to arrive at the expression to be injected.

Many thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `RuleDelayed`, `a[t] :> ...` etc. without all the `Hold` stuff?

Comment: @Michael E2 Thanks for considering my question, the a[t]:> rhs construction would lead to the same issue, being that the rhs will evaluate to 0 or 1 before injecting. So I would inject a[t]->1 in my case and a[t]:>1 in your suggestion. Probably my question should be phrased more generic, however I am able to solve some scoping problems and I am struggling with this specific one. So I do not understand what is the scoping problem I am dealing with in the specific WhenEvent case, hence a more specific question.

Comment: @Michael E2 I update my question to put more emphasis on this.